A model decomposing umlauts
A while ago I posted a software request at the assorted Exchange, for a library that would correctly transform umlauts into their base characters. Apparently such a thing does not currently exist in a useful capacity.
Since then, two notions have occured to me that motivate me to open this follow-up over here:

The hardest part in building such a thing may well be to acquire the list of valid mappings (e.g. 'ǿ -> oe') in the first place.
Word Nets* are tools for matching content in texts using purely structural transformations such as filtering stop words and other kinds of normalisation.
My task is a task of normalisation. (E.g. many forms require users to not enter umlauts, so any Word Net to be fed such forms among other data would have to normalise the umlauts on either side.)

It seems conceivable to me, that for some linguistic purpose or another, someone may well have created such a mapping (most likely as part of a greater transformation pipeline).
Is there a (work-in-progress of a) systematic overview of umlaut decompositions accessible to the public?
Such an overview would presumably have to contain two major components:

the mappings, always beginning with one umlaut and ending with a string of non-umlaut characters of the same alphabet
rules that allow picking the correct mapping, e.g. depending on language**, alphabet(?)***, and possibly other, unknown to me, restrictions
(It may well be that such restrictions, ultimately, do not exist - I would not know and "it is hard to prove a negative".)

* - Note on the wording: In ~2008, when I first learned about this technology, "Word Net" was what it was called in the abstract. I read a book back then, with the same title, describing the principles on how any such Word Net implementation may operate. But now that I look up the term, to ensure I do not misremember, I can only find one specific application "WordNet" and a book that glorifies this particular implementation, but nothing about a generic technique or whole class of applications. I do recall that my university alone had multiple Word Nets in use for different projects, but nowadays apparently "there can be only one"?
** - E.g. I have been told that Danish 'ø -> oe'  but Norwegian 'ø -> o'.
*** - If the alphabet has a long s, then German 'ß -> ſs' but if not, then 'ß -> ss'.
No idea if there may be cases not trivially post-processed. (No information is lost by always mapping 'ß -> ss'.)

To use a programming metaphor, it's sort of like asking "how do I convert JSON to XML". There are dozens of different standards for converting JSON to XML for specific purposes, so it'll depend on why you're doing the conversion—what's your end goal here? Using the wrong standard won't work at all, for normalization purposes—the program is expecting one particular XML schema and won't accept a different one. And in this case, there are different standards for passports, libraries, usernames on old-school ASCII-only systems…
While you can replace ß with ss and still be understood, for example, it is not a lossless transformation: a classic example is the difference between in Massen (in large quantities) versus in Maßen (in moderation). So, do you really need a lossless transformation? German-speakers will do fine with ss (some places, like Switzerland, already do this as a general rule), and probably prefer it over something like ss', but if your goal is to round-trip your text through an ASCII-only system without losing information, something like ss' will be necessary to avoid ambiguity. Once again, it depends on your goal in the normalization.

In German German there is exactly one way to decompose äöüß. I could not think up a good example of where it would be context-dependent, but the possibility I have explicitly accounted for in the question. ... I do not know how to express this properly, but I am explicitly not interested in what issues the rules have (e.g. losing information as per your 'Massen/Maßen' example), as long as I can follow them. E.g. on a print form, I am always supposed to do 'ß -> SS' (ALLCAPS). If I have to write 'Maße' on such a form, the ambiguity is the issue of the issuer, not mine.

FWIW: I would expect, that there is no generative model for this task, but a list/mapping ought to be finite, presumably quite short per language, and for all entries there ought to be experts who can write them down from memory without issues... but I could never do it all on my own, nor could I round up all such experts, thence I'd have hoped for some sort of... "anthology", presumably worked on by many people over many years? Wiktionary is such a project, but it cannot answer this particular question.

@Zsar There definitely are short lists like that; the problem is, they depend on the purpose you're aiming for. ä > ae, ß > ss is standard for things like passports, but since it's not lossless, it's not appropriate for things like URLs.
